# How to get setuptools and easy_install?

Tags: python, egg

I downloaded the `ez_setup` code from here: http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py
and ran it, but i don't think `setuptools` was properly installed. When i try to open an egg using `easy_install` i am getting a NameError. Any thoughts?

Here is the specific error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:...setup.py", line 223, in <module>
    easy_install eggsetup.py
NameError: name 'easy_install' is not defined
```

Comment: are you on ubuntu? `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools`

Comment: Ubuntu with `File C:` ?

Comment: On Ubuntu, there is also `sudo apt install python3-setuptools`

Answer (score 98):

For linux versions(ubuntu/linux mint), you can always type this in the command prompt:

`sudo apt-get install python-setuptools`

This will automatically install `easy_install`.

Comment: I wish it was but this version is so old things will not install properly (like Buildout).

Comment: After doing this, another install which depends on setuptools *still* tells me that setuptools isn't installed!

Answer (score 37):

For python3 on Ubuntu

```
 sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
```

Answer (score 12):

please try to install the dependencie with pip, run this command:

```
sudo pip install -U setuptools
```

Comment: And see other links to help with pip install:
https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/install-pip-for-python/
 and https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Answer (score 11):

**2021 update:**

- `easy_install` no longer exists, it was replaced by `pip install`.
- `setuptools` is built-in with Python 3. It's the package to read package files (wheels) and do things under the hood.
- `pip` is built-in with Python 3.
- `venv` is built-in with Python 3.

Some operating systems (Debian) like to split packages into smaller independent packages, you may have to `sudo apt-get install python3 python3-pip python3-venv` to get all the executables. Nonetheless, the tools are usually available even if the command isn't exposed, try calling `python3 -m pip install ...`.

Comment: voted up for `sudo apt install python3-venv`

Answer (score 6):

```
apt-get install python-setuptools python-pip
```

or

```
apt-get install python3-setuptools python3-pip
```

you'd also want to install the python packages...

Answer (score 3):

Give this link a try --> https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

I'm assuming you're on Windows (could be wrong) but if you click the green Downloads button, it should take you to a table where you can choose to download a .exe version of setuptools appropriate for your version of Python. All that eggsetup stuff should be taken care of in the executable file.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Pypi is great, but i need vanilla C-interpreted Python. Any ideas?

Comment: @dopatraman, I think you're thinking of PyPy, not to be confused with Pypi.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu until python-distribute is something newer than 0.7 I'd recommend:

```
$ wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py -O - | sudo python
```

See http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2013/07/08/new-setuptools-buildout.html

Comment: link https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py is 404

Comment: PyPa lives on GitHub now. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56357346/943773) for install directions.

Answer (score 1):

For Amazon Linux AMI

```
yum install -y python-setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing from distro packages, then this probably doesn't apply to your scenario...

## recompile python

I have multiple versions of Python built from source installed, and I found I didn't have `setuptools` for version 3.5. It seems like I was [missing the `zlib`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3905615/943773) libraries when I compiled 3.5, which subsequently made the `setuptools` install fail quietly (to me at least). Recompiling with the `zlib` libs installed fixed this for me.

## install from GitHub

If you are for some reason missing `setuptools` and have Python compiled with all the necessary libs, you should be able to install it from the GitHub repo like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/pypa/setuptools.git
cd ./setuptools
python3.5 bootstrap.py
sudo python3.5 setup.py install
```

Comment: ^This right here should be the top comment. Unfortunately, effective as of April 2018, `python-setuptools` no longer ships with `easy_install`, as per Matthias's update:
https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-main-i386/python-setuptools_39.0.1-2_all.deb.html
However, you can still compile from the source code yourself, and it does work. I just tried it with `sudo easy_install shodan`, and it ran successfully.