# Have installed the `zlib` but still get the error. RuntimeError: Compression requires the (missing) zlib module

Tags: python, setuptools

Read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905615/zlib-module-missing)

I have installed the `zlib` and `zlib-devel` in my CentOS7.2.

But why when I install the setuptools still get this error?

```
cd setuptools-19.6 

python3 setup.py build

python3 setup.py install
```

the error:

```
...
File "/root/setuptools-19.6/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 223, in run
    dry_run=self.dry_run, mode=self.gen_header())
  File "/root/setuptools-19.6/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 464, in make_zipfile
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, mode, compression=compression)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1098, in __init__
    _check_compression(compression)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 647, in _check_compression
    "Compression requires the (missing) zlib module")
RuntimeError: Compression requires the (missing) zlib module
```

my Python3 version is `Python 3.6.0a1`.

---

**EDIT-01**

I get the `setuptools` by:

```
wget --no-check-certificate  https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-19.6.tar.gz#md5=c607dd118eae682c44ed146367a17e26
```

---

**EDIT-02**

I use the `40.0.0` [setuptools](https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/), still this issue.

Comment: Why you want such an ancient version of setuptools?

Comment: @wim see my edit-01.

Comment: that doesn't explain why you are using such an old version

Comment: you will probably get more help using one of the more recent releases from https://pypi.org/simple/setuptools/

Comment: @avigil I tried the last version of setuptools, still not work.

Comment: you are probably using a python built without zlib support. The error you are getting is because the `zlib` module is missing (`python3 -c "import zlib"` should fail). Thats something that gets added on python build so adding the libraries after the fact would not help.

Comment: @avigil  seems right - did you ./configure && make this python 3.6.0a1 interpreter yourself?  Why do you want to use an old alpha when 3.6.5 final (and indeed 3.7.0) is out - it could be easily installed in CentOS using yum?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because of you install the `zlib` and `zlib-devel` after make install `python`.

now your solution should be re-make install the python. in your python directory `make && make install`.

and then go to setuptools for install:

```
python3 setup.py build
python3 setup.py install
```

Comment: For Homebrew users, run `brew reinstall python@2`.